# Code Mirror to Edit the whole web page?

Tags: jquery, codemirror

Is is Possible to edit a whole web page with code mirror?

Instead of using getElementById('editor') and then creating a `<div id="editor"></div>`

I have an index.php and I would like to add code mirror at the bottom of my page and edit the whole page with code mirror - Just like as if I was inspecting the web page with firebug and editing the html that way and the changed text would update my web page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

        <title>Editing the whole web page</title>

        <base href="/"> 


        <meta name="description" content="descritption here" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="keyword1, keyword2, keyword3" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="author" content="" />


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../lib/CodeMirror/lib/codemirror.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../lib/CodeMirror/theme/monokai.css">
        <script src="../lib/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="../lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>   





        <link rel="canonical" href="/" />

<style type="text/css" media="screen">
.CodeMirror {font-size: 16px; z-index: 999999999;}
</style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <h1>Hello world!</h1>
<p> some text on my page </p>



<script src="../lib/CodeMirror/lib/codemirror.js" ></script>
<script src="../lib/CodeMirror/mode/xml/xml.js" ></script>
<script src="../lib/CodeMirror/mode/javascript/javascript.js" ></script>
<script src="../lib/CodeMirror/mode/css/css.js" ></script>
<script src="../lib/CodeMirror/mode/vbscript/vbscript.js" ></script>
<script src="../lib/CodeMirror/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js" ></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var config, editor;

    config = {
        lineNumbers: true,
        mode : "xml",
        htmlMode: true,
        theme: "monokai",
        tabMode: "indent",
        matchBrackets: true,
        indentWithTabs: true,
        readOnly: false
    };

    // the below only retrieves the get element by id :/
    //editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById(""), config);

    function selectTheme() {
        editor.setOption("theme", "monokai");
    }
    setTimeout(selectTheme, 5000);
</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks,
Michel

Comment: How about dynamically creating an overlay-textarea with the whole HTML content (read via DOM) and editing this?

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow you, but I did try to wrap my whole page with <textarea id="someid"></textarea>, but 1. my web page breaks & 2. I'd like to see my content being updated just like as if I was inspecting the page with firebug and edit html that way and see results happening on the page

Comment: I woud dynamically create the textarea and insert your HTML inside that dynamically created textarea, then display it screen-filling (e.g. inside an overlay-DIV).

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the syntax? Would it be like <script>$('html').wrap('<textarea></textarea>'); </script>, not sure about the overlay div or how it would work